# How to detect all the key press events across any application and map certain sequences to commands?

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, xorg

I want to write a piece of code that detects all the key press events across all the applications. The code would then map certain specific sequences to a command I define.

For e.g.if I press **c,h,r,o,m,e**, the code detects this sequence and opens chrome.

The subtlety I'm not aware of is how can I detect all the key press events across all the applications.

My findings and investigation
 1. I read about the device files in /dev/input. It looks like there exists a file for each of the input device and so, I may be able to read that file corresponding to the keyboard. Although, I'm not sure what are the semantics for those device files.
2. I know that there is a way to define custom keyboard shortcuts in ubuntu 18.04 by navigating to settings->keyboard. But those shortcuts require that all the keys in the shortcut be held down to trigger the command. But that's not feasible for the scenario I want to implement. I'm expecting the sequences to be moderately long, long enough that it is difficult to hold down all keys at once.

Comment: Look at the [source code of `evtest`](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/evtest/tree/evtest.c). It's actually quite readable. I've used it to create my own keyboard grabber.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the relevant details in a 2 part post on linuxjournal.com. The post details the input subsytem for linux kernel in a beginner friendly way.

- https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6396
- https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6429

Further, here is a link to source code of [evtest](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/evtest/tree/evtest.c). Credits for this link goes to [Ruslan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/673852/ruslan)